Touching up veneer cabinets
We just bought a house and the cabinets need some sprucing up. They look like veneer. There’s a lot of scratches on the sides, and the current hardware is really chunky and not our style (knobs have two holes about 1.5 in apart) so I would like to ideally fill in those holes. The guy at Sherwin Williams told me to use wood filler and a little bit of gel stain on the parts that need touching up. Any advice?

Pictures would help.

There are a number of different types of cabinet finishes. The processes that work with some don't work with others.  We really need to know what make-up of cabinets you have.  Pics will help.

Agree with the above and also photos of the general condition of the room - walls, trim, floor, etc and your intentions regarding level of perfection you are looking for.   Do the repairs have to be invisible or just be better than holes and missing veneer?

Wood filler and stain is going to be a "repair" you can spot from 10 feet away.
Whether that bothers you more or less than "chunky hardware" is a decision only you can make.
There being about 100,000 options in cabinet hardware, try looking for other hardware with holes 1-1/2" apart that you like the look of better, unless you like stained wood filler a lot.
Or glue a piece of matching or contrasting wood (contrasting being easier than trying to match) over the holes before adding new hardware (also known as the "make it a feature" approach.)
If the scratches are not through the veneer you should be able to sand and refinish to address those - assuming it's actually wood veneer, not some sort of printed plastic overlay (which are quite common on MDF cabinets trying to fake the look of real wood.) Don't overdo the sanding, modern veneers are quite thin.

This is good advice. Sure, you can get acceptable results with filler and stain - if you spend a week trying different combinations of filler and stain until you find one that blends in. Ain't nobody got time for that, unless you're one of those obsessive tweakers that I see on YouTube furniture restoration videos.
